In WCF, why use HttpBinding instead of netTcpBinding?
WCF has netTcpBinding and HttpBinding. TCP is a transport layer protocol. HTTP is an application layer protocol which by default uses TCP. I read that netTcpBinding is faster than HTTP. If so, why use HttpBinding at all? What are the different scenarios where you would pick HttpBinding over netTcpBinding?
On a related note, I read that TCP ports are blocked by firewalls. Why is this?
I read that netTcpBinding uses a Microsoft propriety protocol in the application layer. Is this true?

Some networking environments limit themselves to HTTP(S) - that's the main reason for using the HTTP binding over the TCP one, I believe. --- Ports are blocked to prevent unauthorized access - it's a security measure that can be controlled, i.e. you (an admin) can open specific ports for access as the needs arise.

TCP transfers are really fast. But it's used on the intranet network. Normally, our WCF is used for server-client and is invoked over the Internet.
And a lot of networks and projects use https. It's much safer. However, Nettcpbinding cannot use https.
NetTcpBinding:
Very high performance
Use on an internal network
use HTTTP/HTTPS protocol
HTTP/HTTPS is not supported
BasicHttpBinding / WSHttpBinding::
Cross-network and firewall
HTTP/HTTPS is supported
Slightly slower than Nettcpbinding
use TCP protocol
